# Is there a way to get the previous url in Microsoft WebView2 (WPF .NET6)

Tags: wpf, .net-6.0, webview2

I was wondering if there is a way to get the previous URL from WebView2 in WPF 
 eg. something like: `string foo = WebView2.CoreWebView2.PreviousURI();`

Comment: Do you simply want to navigate back?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any such property available but you could easily keep track of the previous URL yourself by handling the `NavigationStarting` event and store the URL being navigated from in a variable, e.g.:

```
private Uri _previousSource;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    webView.NavigationStarting += WebView_NavigationStarting;
}

private void WebView_NavigationStarting(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs e) =>
    _previousSource= webView.Source;
```